# What is the meaning of "Won't I/we" in questions?

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs, interrogatives, will-shall

I understand that *won't* in negative declarative sentences expresses unwillingness or a refusal.

- e.g. *I **won't** leave until I've seen the manager.*

So, what does *won't* express in **negative interrogative** sentences with **first person subjects?** For example:

> 1. ***Won't I** leave?*
> 2. ***Won't we** go?*

**QUESTION:** What is the meaning of "won't" in the above two examples, and how do the above two examples differ in meaning from their positive counterparts *"Will/Shall I leave?"* and *"Will/Shall we go?"* ?

Comment: Do you understand the same question phrased positively ("Will we go?")? This appear to be the same question phrased negatively.

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine *Will we go?* first:

> Will we go?

You are in a group of people, speaking for the group, and asking the entire group if everyone in it wants to go.

It can also be a shortened form of *Will we go next?* - in a situation such as a group waiting their turn for an amusement park ride or similar.

> Won't we go?

This is *will we go* in the negative (*will we not go?*)  You are in a group of people, speaking for the group, and asking the entire group if everyone in it does not wish to go.

Sometimes questions use this negative form (auxillary verb + not) as a shallow form of indirection, "softening," or politeness.  The positive form is more clear but also more direct which may not be wanted in somewhat more polite or "begging" situations:

> Can't we go to the park, Dad? (used as if it were *Can we go to the park, Dad?*)
>
> Haven't we done this before? (used as if it were *Have we done this before?*)
>
> Shouldn't we stop doing this now? (etc...)
>
> Wouldn't he have known that?

"Won't we go?" follows the same principle.

---

---

Similarly:

> Will I leave?

You are asking someone if you are going to leave.

Typically, the stress will be on the *I*, meaning the speaker/writer wants to confirm he/she is the one that is going to leave.

This also may come up if the speaker/writer is discussing a plan of some sort and wants to know if he/she will leave at some determined time, the determined time being understood from the context.

> Won't I leave?

As explained with *won't we go*, this would be an indirect, "soft", or polite form of *will I leave.*

Answer (score 1):

The negative interrogative means technically the same thing as its positive counterpart, but it *connotates* or *implies* that the answer is probably yes.  They are normally rhetorical questions.  For example if you were about to exit into a snowstorm and your friend was in a shirt, you might say `won't you put a coat on?`